# Gather stats on partition table by serial method

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, statistics

Can anyone please tell the syntax for gather statistics on partition table by serial method instead of parallel method.

I am using below query, am not sure whether it is by serial method

```
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats 
  (ownname  => 'OWN_NAME',
   tabname  => 'TAB_NAME', 
   partname => 'P20171231');
```

Comment: But why do you want to make it `serial` when `parallel` is always best. I hope you understand what you mean when you say you want to do a job serially rather parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There is param degree. Pass 1 to use serial for sure. Default is DEFAULT_DEGREE_VALUE which takes value from global preference. Full details are here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68664